# Iterating over an array of dicts with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one area of my HTML file I am setting a scope variable like so:

```
$scope.my_data = [
                {
                        c1: "r1c1",
                        c2: "r1c2",
                        c3: "r1c3",
                        c4: "r1c4",
                },
                {
                        c1: "r2c1",
                        c2: "r2c2",
                        c3: "r2c3",
                        c4: "r2c4",
                },...
        ];
```

Then I want to iterate over it with `ng-repeat`. So I do the following:

```
<tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in my_data">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="(column, value) in row">
               <td>{$ column $}</td>
               <td>{$ value $}</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

However I'm not seeing anything come out for column and value

If I do `(row_num, row) in my_data` row_num accurately has the index and row has the correct dictionary.  Now I want to expand the dictionary

Comment: Mmm are you sure that you want `{$ column $}` and not `{{ column }}`?

Comment: @wil93 I am using a different start and end symbol via interpolateProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have the `<tr data-ng-repeat="(column, value) in row">` nested within the other `tr` tag ends up being invalid html to say the least.  I'm not sure what your end goal is but if you just want the data display, you could have nested tables for the second `ng-repeat`:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="row in my_data">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="(column, value) in row">
              <td>{{column}}</td>
              <td>{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This produces the output that I believe you are seeking, but nested tables can be a formatting nightmare.